# Is there a way to call quick parts from Fluent UI xml?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, ribbon-control

I would like to be able to create a custom UI in Word 2007/2010 to call quick parts/auto-texts from the custom ribbon.

I can call macros and other coded things fine, but is there a way to integrate quickparts in a custom ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to integrate one of the built-in CustomGallery controls (or another built-in gallery) into the ribbon:

```
<mso:cmd app="Word" dt="1" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab id="myCustomTab" label="My Custom Tab" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
                <mso:group id="myCustomGroup" label="My QuickParts" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:gallery idQ="mso:CustomGallery1" showInRibbon="false" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

Comment: Is there a way to define new galleries?

Comment: Yes, you can create new QuickParts and place them in a custom gallery. However, you are limited to the 5 built-in custom galleries.